# ACF google map not working on wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF pro version. I already added the below code on function.php file. but there is problem with API key. working only main site and map not showing on blog sites :(. can any one help me to fix this.

```
function my_acf_init() {
    acf_update_setting('google_api_key', 'AXXX');
}

add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

**Oops! Something went wrong.**

This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see on the JavaScript console in your browser?

Comment: Under the [Template usage](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) of ACF document, "Please also note that the Google API is required for this to work and is included in the required JS below. The Google Map API is a great library to render a map, however, it is not the only API available. Please consult Google for any other API’s and tutorials." Check [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) of Google for additional information about Google Maps JS API.

Comment: @bamnet it's showing API key problem